# Oracle variables escaping in select statement

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, variables

I am trying to use variables to retrieve XML using Oracle, this is the XML:

```
<data type="TestType" version="1">
  <MasterTable Name="TestMaster"/>
  <Table Name="Test1">
    <test id="1">testText</test>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="TestTable1"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable2"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable3"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable4"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable5"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable6"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable7"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable8"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable9"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable10"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable11"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable12"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable13"/>
</data>
```

I have the below SQL:

```
declare
SEARCH_NODE nvarchar2(50) :='data' ;
NODE_NO nvarchar2(50) :='1' ;
DISPLAY nvarchar2(50) :='@version' ;
V_XML_RETRIEVED nvarchar2(50) ;

BEGIN
    SELECT a.XML.EXTRACT('//'||SEARCH_NODE||'['||NODE_NO||']/'||DISPLAY||'').GETSTRINGVAL() into V_XML_RETRIEVED FROM test_table a ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_XML_RETRIEVED);
END;
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: ''
ORA-06512: at line 8
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

I think this is likely to do with the escape characters but cannot figure out what it should be!

The below does work, which is the same thing but without variables:

```
declare
V_XML_RETRIEVED nvarchar2(50) ;

BEGIN
    SELECT a.XML.EXTRACT('//data[1]/@version').GETSTRINGVAL() into V_XML_RETRIEVED FROM test_table a ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_XML_RETRIEVED); -- returns version "1"
END;
```

Comment: where is `execute immediate` in your code?

Comment: Is your column `XMLTYPE` data type or `VARCHAR2/CLOB`?

Comment: @Kaushik there isn't one, is it required?

Comment: @Wernfried it is `XMLTYPE`

Comment: Change `||DISPLAY||'')` to `||DISPLAY)`

Comment: Your question says "within execute immediate" , so I was searching to find it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit that doesn't seem to work, it has a red line under that part and when run displays the following error: `Error report -
ORA-06550: line 8, column 74:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action`

Comment: @KaushikNayak Ah yes, I have now changed this. I did have the statement in an execute immediate but that wasn't working either.